# cuda reach device function from global

Tags: cuda

I am trying to call a device function from global function. This function is only declaring an array to be used by all threads. But my problem when I printed the array its elements are not in the same order as declared. Is it because of all threads are creating the array again ? I confused about threads. If it is , Can I learn which thread is run first in global function and can I only allow it to declare the array for the others. Thanks.
Here my function to create array :

```
__device__ float myArray[20][20];

__device__ void calculation(int no){
filterWidth = 3+(2*no);
filterHeight = 3+(2*no);
int arraySize = filterWidth;
int middle = (arraySize - 1) / 2;
int startIndex = middle;
int stopIndex = middle;

// at first , all values of array are 0
for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++)
    {
        myArray[i][j] = 0;
    }

//  until middle line of the array, required indexes are 1
for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
{
    for (int j = startIndex; j <= stopIndex; j++)
    { myArray[i][j] = 1; sum+=1; }
    startIndex -= 1;
    stopIndex += 1;
}

// for middle line
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{myArray[middle][i] = 1; sum+=1;}

// after middle line of the array, required indexes are 1
startIndex += 1;
stopIndex -= 1;
for (int i = (middle + 1); i < arraySize; i++)
{
    for (int j = startIndex; j <= stopIndex; j++)
    { myArray[i][j] = 1; sum+=1; }
    startIndex +=1 ;
    stopIndex -= 1;
}


filterFactor = 1.0f / sum;
  }
```

And global function :

```
__global__ void FilterKernel(Format24bppRgb* imageData)
  {
int tidX = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int tidY = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

Colour Cpixel = Colour (imageData[tidX + tidY*imageWidth] );
float depthPixel =  Colour(depthData[tidX + tidY*imageWidth]).Red;
float absoluteDistanceFromFocus = fabs (depthPixel - focusDepth);


if(depthPixel == 0)
    return;

Colour Cresult = Cpixel;
for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    calculation(i);
     ...
     ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where do you declare the variable `myArray` ... and it looks like you're calling `filterKernel` inside of `calculation` and vice versa. You're missing the final closing braces to the function definitions. Try to clean up the code a bit so we can have a better look.

Comment: I didn't paste whole global function because of long. And declared the array at top as device.And after I finished creating myArray , Iwas converting it 1d array filterKernel. but not important I deleted it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to select and force one thread to call the function and the rest to wait for it to do so, use `__shared__` memory for the array created by the device function so that all threads in a block see the same one, and you can call it with:

```
for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    if (threadIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.y == 0)
        calculation(i);
    __syncthreads();
    ...
}
```

Of course, this won't work between blocks - in a globally defined function, you have no control over the order in which blocks are computed.

Instead, if you can, you should do the initialization calculation (that only 1 thread needs to do) on the CPU and memcpy it to the GPU before launching your kernel. It looks like you'll use 8x the memory for your myArray's, but it'll dramatically speed up your computation.

Comment: Sorry I did as you said . I called the function inside if loop and still when I print it is printing many times in different order.I don't have much knowledge about cuda.Also If I got true, you say deckare function in CPU and copy to GPU. But I need to call GPU once time. If I do like that , I will need to call GPU each time , isn't it?

Comment: It seems like you want each thread to do some other stuff inside the for-loop but access a shared array, and you are initializing the shared array in the computation function -- the only argument the computation function takes is `i`, which varies from 1 to 8. Instead, create 8 arrays on the CPU, do `computation` 8 times on the 8 CPU arrays, `cudamalloc` and `cudamemcpy` them to the GPU, and call the kernel once -- each thread now does the same thing, but instead of `computation(i)` it sets `int* localArray = myArray[i]`.

Comment: Ok I understood what you mean. first I didn't want to do it because max array size will be 17 and to be better I wrote the function to create array. It seems there is no way to call the function once time from global with first thread or to share others. Thank you for your answers

Comment: Actually, try the code above, but launch the kernel with 1 block - it should work. Synchronizing across blocks however is both difficult and results in terrible performance.

Comment: For the above code , I made my Array :extern  __shared__  and when calling kernel for shared memory size I wrote 100 : FilterKernel<<<gridDim, blockDim ,100>>> . But how can I call Kernel with 1 block and later change ? I didn't know this . And is there any wrong thing I wrote?

Comment: Leave the array a `__device__`, and change `gridDim to (1,1)`. This should 'work' in the sense that only 1 thread (the first in the block) will call `calculation(i)` and the others will wait for it to finish. But there's no point experimenting with this, since you can't scale this to more blocks.

Comment: ok then i can't use it for more blocks. So writing each array instead of calling with function will be simple. Thanks